# Is type coercion more dangerous inside a conditional?

Tags: javascript, types, conditional-statements, coercion

I just read this in a [blog post](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/03/things-every-javascript-developer-should-know/):

> If you want to coerce values, do so outside of the condition not within it.

I'm curious. In Javascript, is it worse to use type coercion in a conditional than outside of one? Are there any side effects?

Example code:

```
var initInt = 1
, initString = '1'

// Outside of a conditional
var coerceType = initInt == initString

if (coerceType === true) { 
  console.log('True') 
}

// Inside of a conditional

if (initInt == initString) { 
  console.log('True') 
}
```

Comment: What was their explanation for that blanket generalization?

Comment: That comment is made in the section about using `===` instead of `==`.  The suggestion here is to make the coercion more explicit by separating it and always using `===` in every conditional.

Comment: One thing to understand is `==` does type coercion, however `===` does not. So instead of relying on `==` to coerce a variable type you do so beforehand so you know the variable type is what you want it to be for your comparison

Comment: j08691 - They didn't have one. That's what I'm curious about.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like their point is simply that you should not use `==` to do type conversion (or at all, for that matter).

Using type coercion inside a conditional is fine, as long as it's abundantly clear what's happening:

```
if (myNum === +myNumString)
```

but the `==` operator has a lot of quirky, inconsistent, and hard to remember behavior, as described in that blog post.

It's for this reason that a lot of people recommend against using the `==` operator at all.

[Further Reading](http://conceptf1.blogspot.jp/2014/01/javascript-triple-equals-vs-double-equals-operators.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that `myNum === +myNumString` is actually better than `==`  - that `+` is pretty easy to ignore. Something like `(myNum === + myNumString)` might help that. 

Does the `==` operator have any inconsistent behavior I would not expect of other type coercers?

Comment: @RichLitt I'm not referring to visibility but rather to predictability. `+` may not be all that easy to see, but it's quite clear what it does - coerces a value to a number or `NaN` (which is technically a kind of number). The behavior of `==` is complicated, bizarre, and confusing, and that's why it's eschewed. For example `24 == '24'` is true, but `true == 'true'` is false (what?). `' \t\r\n ' == 0` is true somehow. And the worst part: `0 == '0'` is true, `0 == ''` is true, and `'' == '0'` is false. That's basically like saying A equals B, B equals C, and A is not equal to C.